# `CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER` requires super permissions

Tags: mysql

I am importing one of my old databases to my new database.

To do this, I created a user with the same privileges as before:

Almost every command seems to work except the following:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`foo`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `wp_affiliate_wp_campaigns` AS select `wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`affiliate_id` AS `affiliate_id`,`wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`campaign` AS `campaign`,count(`wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`url`) AS `visits`,count(distinct `wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`url`) AS `unique_visits`,sum(if((`wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`referral_id` <> 0),1,0)) AS `referrals`,round(((sum(if((`wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`referral_id` <> 0),1,0)) / count(`wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`url`)) * 100),2) AS `conversion_rate` from `wp_affiliate_wp_visits` group by `wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`affiliate_id`,`wp_affiliate_wp_visits`.`campaign`;
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

This is odd as this table was created with a user with the same permissions as my old database (i.e., all permissions for table `foo`).

So my question is:

- What exactly does this command do?
- Why do I suddenly need super permission to execute it when my old database never did?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this identical problem. What worked for me was to take off the:

```
  ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`foo`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

You would then just have:

```
  CREATE VIEW `wp_affiliate_wp_campaigns'...
```

Worked like a charm.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=CURRENT_USER SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```